# Integrate $\frac{e^{itx}}{1-it}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I need this integral to find the probability density function from the characteristic function but I don't know how to find it, every method that I try fails. I tried integration by parts but I didn't get the result that I need to.

The integral is

$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{itx}}{1-it}dt}.$$

The result I need to get by my computations is $e^{-x}$, but I dont know how.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E%7Bitx%7D%2F%281-it%29+dt+ Wolfram dies :P

Comment: i as in $\sqrt{-1}$, right?  Not some arbitrary constant?

Comment: yes it is imaginary i

Comment: The integral is divergent, but it can be interpreted as a Fourier transform of distribution.

Comment: $t \mapsto\frac{1}{1-it}$ is the characteristic function of the exponential distribution with rate 1. So, you could argue via the uniqueness of the characteristic functions, but that would be cheating of course.

Comment: I think you have a sign error on an $i$, in either the exponent or the denominator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we rewrite the expression and interpret it as a Fourier transform:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{1-it} \, dt
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1+it}{1+t^2} e^{itx} \, dt
= \mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{1+t^2} \right\} + \mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{-it}{1+t^2} \right\},
$$
where
$$
\mathcal{F}\{f(t)\} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t) \, e^{-ixt} \, dt
$$

Then, according to [rule 208](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Square-integrable_functions,_one-dimensional),
$$
\mathcal{F}\{ e^{-|t|} \} = \frac{2}{1+x^2}
$$
so by the inversion theorem, [rule 105](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships,_one-dimensional),
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{2}{1+t^2} \right\} = 2\pi \, e^{-|x|}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{1}{1+t^2} \right\} = \pi \, e^{-|x|}.
$$

For the other term we use rule 107 giving
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{ \frac{-it}{1+t^2} \right\}
= -i \mathcal{F}\left\{ t \frac{1}{1+t^2} \right\}
= -i \cdot i \left( \pi \, e^{-|x|} \right)' = -\pi \, \operatorname{sign}(x) e^{-|x|}.
$$

Thus,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{itx}}{1-it} \, dt
= \pi \, e^{-|x|} - \pi \, \operatorname{sign}(x) e^{-|x|}
= \pi \left( 1 - \operatorname{sign}(x) \right) e^{-|x|}
= \pi H(-x) e^{-|x|},
$$
where $H$ is the Heaviside function:
$$
H(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & (x<0) \\
1, & (x\geq 0)
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Why is the second term $\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{\color{blue}{-}it}{1+t^2}\right\}$?

Comment: @J.G. I have made a variable change $t \to -t$ because the Fourier transform uses $e^{-ixt},$ not $e^{ixt}.$

Comment: Ah, it comes down to your sign conventionin defining the FT. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$I_n=\frac 1{2\pi}\int_{-n}^n\frac{e^{itx}}{1-it}dt$$
now let $u=1-it$ $du=-idt\Rightarrow dt=idu$
$$I_n=i\int_{1+in}^{1-in}\frac{e^{(1-u)x}}{u}du=ie^x\int_{1+in}^{1-in}\frac{e^{-ux}}{u}du$$
now we will try and manipulate this integral a bit:
$$\int_{1+in}^{1-in}\frac{e^{-ux}}{u}=\Gamma(0,x(1-in))-\Gamma(0,x(1+in))$$
and your integral is this as $n\to\infty$ with the additional constants at the beginning. Notice that this is undefined/divergent and so we cannot properly express the answer although there way be other interpretations in terms of Fourier